# Can we change browser zoom in/out as per the system display resolution size?

Tags: jquery, css

The issue is if the system has display resolution size of 1920x1080 and the set text size if of 100% then in that case I would like to set browser zoom out to 125% then how can I do that?

I tried

```
document.body.style.zoom = "125%";
```

of jquery but was not able to get the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.zoom {
  zoom: 150%;
}
```

Hope it helps!